# Is this copying values twice?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, c++11, copy

Let's assume I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
     QString a;
     void setA(QString val);
}
```

and implement `setA()` like this:

```
void Foo::setA(QString val)
{
  this->a = val;
}
```

and use it like:

```
Foo f;
QString v = "foo";
f.setA(v);
```

Am I copying the `v` struct twice on stack? one for pass in the argument and other in the assignment within the function, is this right? by rather using `void setA(QString &val);` will avoid copying the object twice because in the first one I'm just copying a reference (a pointer) and not the entire object so the only copy of the object is in the assignment:

```
  this->a = val;
```

Comment: In first case you copy-construct QString to pass it as parameter and then copy-assign it to class member, in second case you only copy-assign it once. So in general you are right.. but QString uses reference count in it's implementation so copying it is not so heavy as could be and pass by value is ok in terms of efficiency.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was one of the cases where the optimizer is permitted to "elide" the excess copy.  By why depend on that, rather than code the clearer: `void Foo::setA(QString const& val)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I copying the v struct twice on stack? one for pass in the argument and other in the assignment within the function, is this right?

That's right. You're passing by value, hence a new object must be constructed (in your case, via the copy constructor).

Now, in the particular case of `QString` (and many other value types in Qt), that operation is very cheap as QString is [*implicitly shared*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) (read: reference counted, with copy on write). In case of other data types, the operation can be expensive.

> by rather using void setA(QString &val)

Or actually by using `setA(const QString &val)`, as you're not modifying the object referenced by `val`. By using a const reference you also allow temporaries to be used:

```
void setA(QString &val);
setA(QString("foo")); // does not compile!

void setA(const QString &val);
setA(QString("foo")); // works
```

> so the only copy of the object is in the assignment

Since your class stores a copy anyhow, then a common pattern (cf. Modern Effective C++ for a big discussion) is to stick to the pass-by-value, and use a move-assignment from the parameter:

```
void setA(QString val) {
    this->a = std::move(val);
}
```

As in this scenario you can save a copy in case of invoking `setA` with a temporary / rvalue (`val` would then get move-constructed, and you would move again, resulting in 2 moves instead of 1 copy + 1 move of the const-reference approach). In case of invoking `setA` with a lvalue, you pay 1 copy + 1 move (instead of 1 copy of the const-reference approach).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) you are not going to have 2 copies.  The copy constructor has:

> This operation takes constant time, because QString is implicitly shared. This makes returning a QString from a function very fast. If a shared instance is modified, it will be copied (copy-on-write), and that takes linear time.

So in this case the only time you only have a copy when you assign `val` to `this->a`

Comment: Assigning `val` to `a` also just creates another reference to the same string. So the characters are not copied at all.